# Is there a way for a browser to give its cookies to a socketIO server

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Is there a way i can get the browser that already has the cookie to post their cookie to the Socket Nodejs server. If this is not possible is there a way for it to post the cookies to a fetch API.

Comment: Do you want to get the cookie in socket set by your server?

Comment: No the cookie is set by some php code

Answer (score 0):

You can try by setting cookie option to `true`:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000, {
  path: '/test',
  serveClient: false,
  // below are engine.IO options
  pingInterval: 10000,
  pingTimeout: 5000,
  cookie: true
});
```

and get the cookie from `socket.request`

```
const cookie = require('cookie');

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  const cookies = cookie.parse(socket.request.headers.cookie || '');
});
```

Reference:

1. https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/index.html#new-Server-httpServer-options
2. https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/index.html#socket-request